# LeafletJS - L.GeoJSON.AJAX function too expensive

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to load the geojson file from [this dataset](https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries) onto a world map using leaflet.js. However, because the dataset is so large, it takes a while to load, and freezes some slower browsers. Is there a way to streamline the L.GeoJSON.AJAX function so it does not stall the browser for several seconds?

Relevant code that loads the GEOJSONdata:

```
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: some_function,
            mouseout: some_other_function,
            click: another_function
        });
    }


    var  worldGeoJSON = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('geo-countries-master/data/worldmap.geojson', {
    style: mapStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });
worldGeoJSON.addTo(map);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `so it does not stall the browser for several seconds?`  Ajax as default is async, so it shouldn't matter how large the dataset, the browser shouldn't be stalling.

Comment: Is it still slow if you remove the `onEachFeature` function? Guessing that gets called after the AJAX load and may be synchronous.

Comment: Actually, the bulk of the slowness is eliminated if I remove       `worldGeoJSON.addTo(map);`- That seems to be the source of the problem, though there's nothing I can really do about that, I guess